# How do I find Excel sheet with wrong used range?

Tags: applescript, ms-office

How do I convert this VBA code to AppleScript? The code finds used last row and column from used range and compares it with the last row and column using Find. I would like a text file to be created with a list of worksheets that have issues.

```
Sub DefinedPrintArea2() 'with.find
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim myfile As String
    Dim textfile As Integer
    
    myfile = SelectFolder & "\test file3.txt"         'select the folder where you want tosave the text folder
    textfile = FreeFile
    Open myfile For Output As textfile
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Worksheets(sht.Name).Activate
        With Sheets(sht.Name)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
        lastcol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            lastrow = 1
            lastcol = 1
        End If
        End With
        lastrow2 = sht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        lastcol2 = sht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
        If lastrow > 40 Or lastrow2 > 40 Then
        lastrow = 40
        lastrow2 = 40
        End If
        If lastrow <> lastrow2 Or lastcol <> lastcol2 Then
            Print #textfile, "there's a problem with the sheet " & sht.Name & " , please check"
            Print #textfile, "last row using used range : " & lastrow2 & ", last column using used range : " & lastcol2
            Print #textfile,
        End If
        
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Select
        sht.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Address
        Next
        Close #textfile
End Sub
```

My AppleScript code so far:
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set myRange to ""

```
set wb to active workbook
set screen updating to false
set maxV to 0
set max_ctr to 0
repeat with ctr from 1 to the count of worksheets in wb
    select worksheet ctr
    tell worksheet ctr
        set ccount to get count of columns of used range
        set rcount to get count of rows of used range
        set rowxcolumn to rcount * ccount
        if rowxcolumn > maxV then
            set maxV to rowxcolumn
            set max_ctr to ctr
            set m_rcount to rcount
            set m_ccount to ccount
        end if
    end tell
    
    set sname to the name of worksheet ctr
    set lastrow to count of rows of used range of worksheet ctr
    set lastcol to count of columns of used range of worksheet ctr
    if lastrow is greater than 40 then
        set lastrow to 40
    end if
    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":"}
    set columnLetters to text item 1 of (get address of (column lastcol) of worksheet ctr without column absolute)
    set name of (get resize range "A1" of worksheet ctr row size lastrow column size lastcol) to "Print_Area"
    save
end repeat
select worksheet max_ctr of wb
display dialog "Max sheet is " & name of worksheet max_ctr & ". Max location is " & m_rcount & ", " & m_ccount
select worksheet max_ctr
activate object cell m_rcount of column m_ccount

set screen updating to true
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
```

end tell

I need to find AppleScript equivalent for this and tie it up:
lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=.Range("A1"), _
Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row